# How Datacontext is specified can not understand

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here in `mMaterialCentreGroupListView.xaml` file, this line is written for `MaterialCentreGroupView` . But I can not see any data context for accessing viewmodel's property. It is working good. Below is code.

```
<vw:MaterialCentreGroupView
            Style="{StaticResource DetailedViewStyle}"
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedMaterialCentreGroup}"/>
```

the view

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyBooks.View.MaterialCentreGroupView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
MinWidth="290" MaxWidth="290" Padding="20"
Background="#eee">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        Content="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=AccountCategoryListView_Name_Label}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="CategoryName"
        MaxLength="50"
        Style="{StaticResource FormControlStyle}"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Please explain to me what happen and how binding is occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the DataContext is either set in the code-behind (file named the same as the .xaml file but with .cs extension). Look for code like DataContext = new SomeViewModel();

Or, if this UserControl is being used within another control, the DataContext could be either explicitly set on it or, if not, it would be inherited from its parent (which may or may not be inherited from its parent, and so on, if not set explicitly in either the XAML or code-behind).

Comment: @StellerEleven : here in materailcenterGroupListView.xaml specify this line <vw:MaterialCentreGroupView DataContext="{Binding SelectedMaterialCentreGroup}"/> and in viewmodel public MaterialCentreGroupViewModel SelectedMaterialCentreGroup{ return _selectedMaterialCentreGroup; } is specified .thanks

Answer (score 0):

look 'Resx' binding

```
<Label 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
    Content="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=AccountCategoryListView_Name_Label}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

more information about resx binding and usage ,refer the below link
[Resx binding and usage](http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/wpf-add-localization-via-resx-files/)